# Whats wrong with my code? (jQuery + HTML)

Tags: jquery, html, href

I'm trying to open a link as soon as you open the page (by forcing a click) with jQuery, but it doesn't work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a.bla').click(function(){
    window.open(this.href);
    return false;
    });
});
</script>   
</head>
<body>
<a href="url-to-open.php" target="_blank" class='bla'><img src="pic.png" alt="" style="border:none;" /></a>
</body>
</html>
```

I have no clue what's wrong. I hope someone of you knows how to fix this.

Comment: Nothing's actually clicking it, but you say that you want it to be clicked as soon as the page loads?

Comment: See Blazemonger's answer in that case :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code will not open a link as soon as you load the page; it creates an *event handler* that triggers a function as soon as you load the page. That event handler is only triggered when you click on the link.

Now, what you would normally do is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a.bla').trigger('click');
});
```

Except that won't open the link, because for security reasons, you can't programmatically trigger a mouse click -- you can only programmatically trigger the *event handler* assigned to that mouse click.

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    window.open($('a.bla').attr('href'),'name-of-new-window');
});
```

Which will work, unless of course the user has a popup blocker stopping it.

Comment: It should open a roster, so that's why I would like to avoid the block. People open the page which says Roster will be opened, but now the roster is blocked. That's why I would like it to be clicked instead of opened, is that possible?

Comment: You can't fake a mouse click that way -- this is a security feature in (probably) every browser. Just put the information in the same page instead of trying to trigger a new browser window -- users are more likely to read it that way anyway.

Comment: If you want a popup then you want the wrong thing.  Use jQuery UI & create a dialog instead - much friendlier and looks a lot better as well (plus you have more control).

Answer (score 1):

```
$('a.bla').click(function(){


should be 

    <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a.bla').click(function(){
    window.open($(this).attr("href"));
    return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Nope. He's looking for the `a` element with the class `bla`

Answer (score 1):

Use `.` for class not `#`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a.bla').click(function(){
    window.open(this.href);
    return false;
    });
});
```

As indicated that using `#` is by mistake.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    window.open($('a .bla').href);
    return false;

});
```

Comment: Yes, that was my old, first I used <div id="">, but i already changed that.

Comment: Updated my answer, you should  open it on .ready instead of click.

Comment: I would like it to be clicked instead of just opened, is that possible?

Comment: Yes, then try first one, but you asked in question to open as soon as page loads.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
window.open($(this).attr('href'));
```

instead of

```
window.open(this.href);
```

If you want to open on page load.. Just move this line outside of the click event and it should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

This example should cause the new window to open automatically via a link click event. (Haven't tested this, may need to pass the `href` value into the handler as a `data` argument.

```
$(document).ready( function() {

    var $link = $( 'a.bla' ),
        href= $link.attr( 'href' );

    $link.unbind( 'click' ).bind( 'click', function ( e ) {
        window.open( href );
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
    } );

    $link.click();
});
```

Comment: I would like it to be clicked instead of just opened, is that possible?

Comment: You want it automatically clicked? (i.e. you want the click event still, but you want it to happen automatically?) If so, i will update my answer.